# Handle java.lang.NullPointerException in scala when accessing nested fields

Tags: java, scala

I have a use case where

```
    name = Person.getFirstSister().getname()
```

`Person.getSister().getname()` gives `java.lang.NullPointerException` since `Person.getSister()` is java null

What is the right way to do this in scala. I am able to achieve with below code. But looking for more scala way of doing it.

```
  private def getFirstSisterName(person: Person): String = {
    val sister = person.getFirstSister()
    if (sister == null) ""
    else sister.getName()
  }
```

Edit:
I changed the code in the following way

```
private def getFirstSisterName(person: Person): Option[String] = 
Option(person).flatMap(l => Option(l.getFirstSister)).map(_.getName)
```

Comment: https://nipafx.dev/java-pirate-elvis-operator/

Comment: There are various typesafe approaches to this in Scala, I suggest you learn more about the language

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip Added my current approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for `null` is the Java way to go. Scala offers a much more streamlined set of operations to avoid doing null checks manually.

Naturally, `getSister` should result in an `Option[Sister]`, the argument being that not every person has a sister.

Going on the same idea, trying to mimic the real word, I would ask: but what if a person has multiple sisters? How do you distinguish between them? This implies your design is not very general because it implies every person has exactly one sister.

So the idiomatic way is to have the method return a `List[Sisters]`. Then `map` their names from the list. If the list is empty, `Nil`, the empty list will be the result, so we won't have any NPE:

```
  case class Sister(name: String)
  case class Person(sisters: List[Sister]) {
    def sistersNames: String = sisters.map(_.name).mkString(" ")
  }

  val p = Person(List(Sister("Sandra"), Sister("Joanna")))
  val p2 = Person(List.empty)

  println(p.sistersNames)    // Sandra Joanna
  println(p2.sistersNames)   // empty String
```

EDIT:

If you can't change `Person` or `Sister`, the alternative is to make your wrapper method treat the null case. You can do this in 2 ways, either use pattern matching, or wrap the result in an `Option`.
**Note**: `Option(x)` checks if `x` is null and if it is, it converts it to a `None`. That is why applying `fold` works.

```
  private def getFirstSisterName(person: Person): String =
    person.getFirstSister match {
      case s: Sister => s.name
      case _         => s"${person.toString} does not have a sister"
    }

  private def getFirstSisterName2(person: Person): String = {
    val sis = Option(person.getFirstSister)
    sis.fold(s"${person.toString} does not have a sister")(_.name)
  }

  val p = new Person(new Sister("Sandra"))
  val p2 = new Person(null)

  println(getFirstSisterName(p))     // Sandra
  println(getFirstSisterName2(p))    // Sandra
  println(getFirstSisterName(p2))    // person827966648 does not have a sister
  println(getFirstSisterName2(p2))   // person827966648 does not have a sister
```

Comment: The classes are java classes and I do not have control over the Person or Sister class. Also the actual class names in my code and use case are very different. Good catch that getSister is poor design. How would you do in scala way without control over those classes.